# Getting CORS error with code 302 while making a GET request to Google auth server from React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

I am trying to add a simple feature i.e  to get all YouTube videos liked by the user.

- In order to access the required YouTube API end point, I need to first authenticate user on Google auth server ([Source: google console](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#protectauthcode)).
- Now my Node-js backend end (running on localhost PORT :4000) will generate needed authorization URL using googleapis.
- When my react frontend makes a GET request to backend route '/log', it will pass the authorization url to frontend (This happens successfully), but when frontend makes a GET request to received  URL, it gets CROS error with message:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

React front end is running on localhost:3000
Node backend is running on localhost:4000.
Also when I paste the authorization URL (received by front end from backend) in browser, it works fine and directs me to Google auth server.

My Front end code is as:

```
const List = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const fun = async () => {
            try {
                const { data } = await axios.get('/log')
            
                await axios.get(data.authorizationUrl) // This request causes error
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.message)
            }
        }

        fun()

   }, [])

    return (

        <div className='list-container'>
 
        </div>
    )
}
```

My backend code is as

```
app.use(cors())
app.listen(4000, console.log('BACKEND RUNING ON PORT:4000'))

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
    YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
    YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
)

const authorizationUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope,
    include_granted_scopes: true
})

app.get('/log', async (req, res) => {
    //...JUST SENDING AUTHORIZATION URL
    res.status(200).json({authorizationUrl})
})
```

Also in package.json of frontend , I have added

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
```

In Google developer console I have added http://localhost:4000 as redirect uri

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are trying to `GET` from the authorization URL programmatically. The purpose of the authorization URL is for the user to visit that URL in a separate browsing context (ex: tab, window) and decide to authorize/not authorize your app to access their information/account/etc. Once they decide, the authorization site will redirect them back to your site, with an authorization token for your site to use to get an access token. Check out [this flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#webserver) for more info.

Because the URL is opened by the user in their browser rather than fetched by your code, your site does not have access to this authorization step. If it did, then your code could maliciously authorize itself to access the users account. The error you are getting is due to the browser blocking your site from doing exactly this. Specifically, it's because the authorization URL does not specify that other websites may `GET` it (your site is not on their 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header).

As a first step, your front end code should instead send a redirect to the auth url, like [shown in this Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#redirecting).